# Launching App from Inno Setup so that setup process closes

Tags: inno-setup

What is the procedure to run/launch an application after a silent setup, so that the Setup installer closes and returns the exit code?

I need this behavior for launcher scripts to detect if setup passed/failed, while the end-user may start to use the app already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`nowait` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=nowait):

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\check.exe"; Flags: nowait
```